# After changing DNS a domain shows differently on different browser?

Tags: domains, dns, browsers, nameserver, firefox

I have changed the nameserver's of one of my domains but I found a problem that within Firefox these changes have not updated as expected, however this problem does not occur in other browsers such as Internet Explorer.

I have refreshed the page and no joy, Why is the nameservers only working for certain browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers cache DNS which is separate from just clearing the cache which deletes temporary files.

*To delete the DNS cache in Firefox follow these easy steps:*

1. Enter `about:config` into the address bar
2. If you receive an acknowledge warning click next
3. Find a option that is labeled `network.dnsCacheExpiration` and set its value to `0`
4. Restart Firefox

In the event you could not find `network.dnsCacheExpiration` simply create one and enter value 0, then after its updated you can put 3600 which I believe is the default.

*Alternatively....*

You could opt to use the easy method of installing an extension, I use [DNS Flusher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dns-flusher/) which is available on the Firefox Extension Library, Simply enable toolbar at the bottom and click the IP address and it'll say FLUSHED. Then hit CTRL F5 or Mac Key F5.

Comment: It's already 1 day and firefox still shows the old pages. Okay I'll try then.

Comment: Hmm... The value was 2592000. I wonder why. Good answer.